# c# Input String was not in a correct format. int.Parse

Tags: c#, string, int

I have a serious problem with c#, this is my code:

```
string priceLowstring = Inventory.exportPrice(price.lowest_price);
string pricestring = Inventory.exportPrice(price.median_price);

Log.Success(priceLowstring);
Log.Success(pricestring);

int priceavg = int.Parse(pricestring);
int priceLow = int.Parse(priceLowstring);
```

And i receive this error:

```
[Gicminos 2016-08-01 11:52:56] SUCCESS: 4
[Gicminos 2016-08-01 11:52:56] SUCCESS: 2
[Gicminos 2016-08-01 11:52:56] ERROR: Unhandled exception occurred in bot: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
....
```

As you can see on Log message, strings are correct and they don't have any spaces..

I checked my `/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/International/sPositiveSign` and it's blank.

What I have to do for resolve that problem?

Comment: "strings are correct" => probably not, as int.Parse fails. Attach a debugger to see the _actual_ string value.

Comment: You can see on "[Gicminos 2016-08-01 11:52:56] SUCCESS: 4" the string value is "4". I'm sure about that.

Comment: I saw that line, but it doesn't mean the value is actually "4". What if there is a non displayable char after the "4" ? No black magic here, no bug in the framework, int.Parse("4") works.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got hidden characters there. You can remove all characters that are not digits:

```
pricestring = new string(pricestring.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

This will fail for you in the case that you have a fraction number - but in any case you want to parse it to int.

*Also - try and use `TryParse` instead of just `Parse` - safer way*